# Open an ionic modal on top of an ionic popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, popup

I'm trying to open a modal page generated from a click in my popup but the modal page stays backward the popup. Any idea how to handle that?

I tried to play with :

```
.popup-open .backdrop {
z-index: 11;
}
```

without success

Comment: I'm using ionic-modal-select so like a normal select, I'd like to select a value to fill a field in my popup.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, just modify $z-index-modal to 13 in SCSS variables.