# Ionic Opening Modal on top of popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I am new to Ionic. While I was playing around with Ionic components, I found that when I try to create modal within popup, the contents inside modal are not able to be clicked.

I found similar question: [Open an ionic modal on top of an ionic popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701678/open-an-ionic-modal-on-top-of-an-ionic-popup)
but no one seems to make suggestions.

Any advice or suggestion?

```
Controller; creates Popup and info_input has a button to open modal.
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        templateUrl: 'templates/info_input.html',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            }
        },
        {
            text: '<span class="selectConfirm">Select</span>',
            type: 'button-dark',
            onTap: function(e) {
                if (!scope.autofill) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    $scope.NextPage(0);
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found temporary solution for this. I have edited **ionic.css file**

```
.popup-open {
  pointer-events:  none; }

to

.popup-open {
  pointer-events: auto; }
```